# mysqldum of database in remote server from localhost

Tags: mysql

$command = "ssh dev@192.168.1.1 ls cd public_html/gforce/hrm mysqldump -uroot -pyipl123 gforce>gforcehrm111.sql";
system($command);
but this code is not working.
How to take a database dump of remote server from localhost.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

let's try the command :

mysqldump -h **your server ip** -P **mysql server port**  -u **user_name** -p **password**  **db name** >**path of your local system where you want to save the dump file**